# Julian Date Convertion Error If Null

Tags: ms-access, vba

Wrote function to convert sudu julian date YDDD to regular date DD/MM/YYYY.

When form populates I get a #Type! in the txt_estimated_delivery_date if the field has no data.

If there is data then everything works.

With a stop on the first line of the function I open the form, I see that the function does not get called until there is data to convert, all others get the #Type!.

An error handler in the funtion does not good because it is only called if there is data for some reason.

Where do I need to put the error correction, in the form or in the control?

Contol Record Source

=JDateToDate([estimated_shipping_date])

```
Function JDateToDate(JDate As String) As Long

Dim TheYear As Integer
Dim TheDay As Integer
Dim TheDate As Long

TheYear = CInt(Left(JDate, 1))

 If TheYear < 30 Then
    TheYear = TheYear + 2010
 Else
    TheYear = TheYear + 1900
 End If

TheDay = CInt(Right(JDate, 3))
TheDate = DateSerial(TheYear, 1, TheDay)
JDateToDate = TheDate

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function expects a String, where a Null is not supported by that type. Try this code.

```
Function JDateToDate(JDate) As String
    Dim TheYear As Integer
    Dim TheDay As Integer

    If IsNull(JDate) Then 
        JDateToDate = vbNullString
        Exit Function
    End If

    TheYear = CInt(Left(JDate, 1))

     If TheYear < 30 Then
        TheYear = TheYear + 2010
     Else 
        TheYear = TheYear + 1900
     End If

    TheDay = CInt(Right(JDate, 3))
    JDateToDate = DateSerial(TheYear, 1, TheDay)
End Function
```

Comment: That works, kind of.  Now anything that was null is now 0 which is displayed as 12/30/1899.

Comment: @Kaw4Life In that case, check the edited code. It will give you an empty String instead of a weird Date.

Comment: Ok - All is well.  Thank you.  Going to try to adapt this to other dates on the same form.